# Java: How to detect a collision between a rectangle and falling circles of varying radius and speed?

Tags: java, geometry, collision, keylistener

to start off, I'm making a simple game in Java that involves a blue rectangle that can be moved with arrow keys and seven falling circles of varying color, radius, and falling speed. Essentially, whenever the rectangle comes in contact with one of these circles, the rectangle will "lose" a life, which will be indicated by 3 rectangles on the top right of a JFrame that I haven't drawn yet. Every time the rectangle is hit by one of these circles, one of the rectangles will disappear, and when the blue rectangle is hit once more, a red "Game Over" text will appear in the middle of the frame.

Now then, although I'm having trouble getting the colors and speed to randomize each time the circles hit the bottom, I'll leave those for a future question. My main concern is the hit detection between the circles and the blue rectangle. I know that I need to define a certain method, but I'm unsure on how to go about doing it, and how to test it for each of the seven circles over and over while they're falling and having their Y value constantly change.

How could I go about doing this? Anyway, here's my main and circles classes for this project. I'm aware that there's a lot of junk code that isn't being used in the main class as well. I'll clean it up after I just figure this out.

**Main class (Keyexample)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.Random;


public class Keyexample extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    private Circle[] Circles = new Circle[7];
    private javax.swing.Timer t2; 
    private Circle newc, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7;
    double x = 100, y = 100;
        double changeX = 0, changeY = 0;
    private int cx = 10, cy = 0;
    private int newcx = 0, newcy = 0;
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private Random colorc = new Random();
    private int n = rand.nextInt(8);


public keyExample() {
    t.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    Random colorc = new Random();
    Random radiusc = new Random();

    int r1 = radiusc.nextInt(12);
    int r2 = radiusc.nextInt(12);
    int r3 = radiusc.nextInt(12);
    int r4 = radiusc.nextInt(12);
    int r5 = radiusc.nextInt(12);
    int r6 = radiusc.nextInt(12);
    int r7 = radiusc.nextInt(12);
    Color cc1 = new Color(colorc.nextInt(255), colorc.nextInt(255),                
        colorc.nextInt(255));
    Color cc2 = new Color(colorc.nextInt(255), colorc.nextInt(255),                                                
        colorc.nextInt(255));
Color cc3 = new Color(colorc.nextInt(255), colorc.nextInt(255),
    colorc.nextInt(255));
Color cc4 = new Color(colorc.nextInt(255), colorc.nextInt(255),
    colorc.nextInt(255));
Color cc5 = new Color(colorc.nextInt(255), colorc.nextInt(255),
    colorc.nextInt(255));
Color cc6 = new Color(colorc.nextInt(255), colorc.nextInt(255),
    colorc.nextInt(255));
Color cc7 = new Color(colorc.nextInt(255), colorc.nextInt(255),
    colorc.nextInt(255));
    //creating the 7 circles and spacing them out
    c1 = new Circle(cx, cy, r1, cc1);
    c2 = new Circle(cx + 50, cy, r2, cc2);
    c3 = new Circle(cx + 100, cy, r3, cc3);
    c4 = new Circle(cx + 150, cy, r4, cc4);
    c5 = new Circle(cx + 200, cy, r5, cc5);
    c6 = new Circle(cx + 300, cy, r6, cc6);
    c7 = new Circle(cx + 400, cy, r7, cc7);

    Circles[0] = c1;
    Circles[1] = c2;
    Circles[2] = c3;
    Circles[3] = c4;
    Circles[4] = c5;
    Circles[5] = c6;
    Circles[6] = c7;

    t2 = new javax.swing.Timer(33, new CircleListener());
    t2.start();
}
//painting rectangle and circles
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40));
        for (int i = 0; i < Circles.length; i++){
        Color circlecolor = new Color(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255),    
            rand.nextInt(255));
    //circle color starts spazzing out here. constantly changing while falling
            g2.setColor(circlecolor);
    Circles[i].fill(g);
}
}


    public void createCircle(){
}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  repaint();
  x += changeX;
  y += changeY;
  changeX = 0;
  changeY = 0;
}

private class CircleListener implements ActionListener {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int move = 2 + rand.nextInt(10);
        int move2 =2 + rand.nextInt(10);
        int move3 =2 + rand.nextInt(10);
        int move4 =2 + rand.nextInt(10);
        int move5 =2 + rand.nextInt(10);
        int move6 =2 + rand.nextInt(10);

        c1.move(0, n);
        position(c1);
        c2.move(0, move);
        position(c2);
        c3.move(0, move2);
        position(c3);
        c4.move(0, move3);
        position(c4);
        c5.move(0, move4);
        position(c5);
        c6.move(0, move5);
        position(c6);
        c7.move(0, move6);
        position(c7);
        repaint();
}
public void position(Circle cp) {
    int height = getHeight();
    int loc = cp.centerX;
    int speed = 3 + rand.nextInt(10);
    int radiuss = cp.radius;
    Rectangle bound = cp.Bounds();  
    if (bound.topY + bound.width > height){
        cp.centerY = 0;
                    //moving circle back to the top
        cp.move(0, speed);
                    //randomizing speed of circle after moving to top, not working
        cp.radius = 5 + rand.nextInt(20);
                    //randomizing radius of circle after moving to top, does work

    }
}
}


     public void up() {
        if (y != 0){
        changeY = -3.5;
        changeX = 0;
      }
}
     public void down() {
        if (y <= 350) {
        changeY = 3.5;
        changeX = 0;
       }
}
     public void left() {
       if (x >=0) {
       changeX = -3.5;
       changeY = 0;
       }
}
     public void right() {
       if (x <= 550) {
       changeX = 3.5;
       changeY = 0;
      }
}
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
       int code = e.getKeyCode();
       if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
       up();
  }
     if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
     down();
  }
     if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
     right();
  }
     if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
     left();
     }
}

     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

**Circle class

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.util.Random;

 public class Circle{

public int centerX, centerY, radius;
public Color color;

public Circle (int x, int y, int r, Color c){
    centerX = x;
    centerY = y;
    radius = r;
Random random = new Random();

}

public void draw(Graphics g){
    Color oldColor = g.getColor();
    g.setColor(color);
    g.drawOval(centerX - radius, centerY - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
    g.setColor(oldColor);
}
public void fill(Graphics g){
    Color oldColor = g.getColor();
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillOval(centerX - radius, centerY - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
    g.setColor(oldColor);   
}
public boolean containsPoint(int x, int y){
    int xSquared = (x - centerX) * (x - centerX);
    int ySquared = (y - centerY) * (y - centerY);
    int radiusSquared = radius * radius;
    return xSquared + ySquared - radiusSquared <=0;
}
public void move(int xAmount, int yAmount){
    centerX = centerX + xAmount;
    centerY = centerY + yAmount;
}
public Rectangle Bounds(){
    int x = centerX - radius;
    int y = centerY - radius;

return new Rectangle(x, y, radius * 2, radius * 2, Color.red);

    }
}
```

Comment: Cleaning out the junk code before posting your question is considered courteous.  I'd start with making a `boolean collidesWith(Rectangle rect)` in your Circle class, filling it in with *your* attempt, and posting that if it doesn't work.

Comment: Box2D uses this approach: `bool collides(Shape a, Shape b, Transform tfA, Transform tfB)` and has specialized methods for each combination of shapes that is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to break the problem into two parts: the first - see if there is "definitely no collision". This happens when the center of the circle is more than a radius away from the edges. It's a very fast test, and will be true most of the time:

```
if(left > x + radius ||
   right < x - radius ||
etc.) { // no collision }
```

The second - if you fail this test, you may still not hit. That depends on whether both x and y are sufficient for overlap. Within this, there are two situations:

1. A corner of the rectangle is inside the circle: easy to compute (distance from one corner to center of circle < r)
2. An edge is inside the circle. This means that in one direction (say X) the center lies between the edges; and in the other direction an edge is less than radius away.

This is general, without actual code. I assume you can write the code from here.

Comment: Thank you! I understand how to write up the mathematical conditions for the collision, but my main problem is actually referencing the coordinates of the blue rectangle that is filled in under paintComponent and comparing it to the circles under the CircleListener class.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect collisions by simple if else conditions on the circle's and rectangle's co ordinates on screen.
distance(circle, Rectangle) <= circle.radius + Rectangle.radius

You can implement distance helper function using the simple distance formula between two points.

[link](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm)